# Plot Multiple Lines with Different Scaling Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, scaling

I'm trying to plot a few waveforms onto the same plot in Matlab; brand new to it. I've tried plotting them all together with plot() but it doesn't scale them all appropriately. How would I go about scaling them? I read something online that uses hold on, but I'm getting the same issue I believe. What's the simple solution here?

```
t1 = 0:0.1:1000;
y1 = t1.^5-5*t1.^3+4*t1;

plot(t1, y1)
hold on

t2 = 0:0.0001:0.01;
y2 = -8*exp(-1000*t2) + 3;

plot(t2, y2)
hold on

t3 = 0:0.0001:0.6;
y3 = exp(-10*t3).*cos(100*t3);

plot(t3, y3)
hold on

%plot(t1, y1, t2, y2, t3, y3)
```

Comment: What would appropriate scaling be? You are plotting three signals with very different time scales, so naturally you can’t plot them to the same axes. Try `subplot`.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is doing what you ask it to do: plotting everything to the same axis system (by the way, you only need to use `hold on` once, it is active until you change the axis or command `hold off`)
You have three options

- define the limits of the axis explicitly, either separately using `xlim([xmin xmax])` and `ylim([ymin ymax])` or jointly using `axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])` (in your case e.g. `axis([0 0.6 0 3.3])`
- you may want to use separate axis in one plot, see [yyaxis](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html) `yyaxis left` / `yyaxis right` to activate the axes. Note that this only provides two different axes scales
- use subplots! (as *Cris Luengo* already stated)
  That would be in your case

```
% 1st subplot
t1 = 0:0.1:1000;
y1 = t1.^5-5*t1.^3+4*t1;

ax(1) = subplot(3,1,1);
plot(t1, y1)

% 2nd subplot
t2 = 0:0.0001:0.01;
y2 = -8*exp(-1000*t2) + 3;

ax(2) = subplot(3,1,2);
plot(t2, y2)

% 3rd subplot
t3 = 0:0.0001:0.6;
y3 = exp(-10*t3).*cos(100*t3);

ax(3) = subplot(3,1,3);
plot(t3, y3)

% link all axes (but only x direction)
linkaxes(ax,'x')
% your axes limits are so large that you probably don't want to link them
```